# Unstacking huge dataset with stock returns

Tags: r, stack, reshape

I have a long CRSP data.frame and I am trying to unstack it to the wide format.

The dataframe contains kypermno (stock identifier), caldat (date yyyy-mm-dd), prc (price), adjprc (adjusted price) and ret (return). The dataframe is sorted by stock (kypermno) and by date (caldat), so each row stands for one stock at a given date.

[image]

The Format I want is: each kypermno as column(name) and each day (date) as row(name) and the returns in the corresponding fields (dropping prc and adjprc).

I tried this: `D_ret <- as.data.frame(unstack(hilfs_ret, ret ~ kypermno))`

The problem is that not all stocks have a return on all days, so I get an error message:

"Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl Zeilen"
(in english: Arguments imply different number of rows)

If a stock does not have a return or did not even exist at that date, there should be a "NA" filling.

This error message does not appear when I skip the "as.data.frame" function, but I want to have a data.frame and not a list.

Solutions with a for loop and if statement is not feasible since the dataset is very large (48 million entries).

Is there anyway to solve this? Maybe with the reshape function?

Thank you very much for your help and have a nice day!

kind regards

kb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use functions from the `tidyverse` collection of packages. Let's say your data frame is called "long_df." Then this code should convert it to a data frame named "wide_df."

```
library(tidyverse)
wide_df <- tidyr::spread(long_df %>% select(-prc, -adjprc), 
                         key= kypermno,
                         value = ret)
```